# How to make Google Chat App Available To Test?

Tags: google-workspace, google-hangouts

I enable the oauth screen fill up the name and set the google app to testing, added 2 users from my workspace (me an another person), and I can't see the chat app/bot in the marketplace internal apps or in the chat application.
Why it doesn't show?